# Css full height for some div

Tags: html, css

Here I have a simple layout that I want to design

[image]

but in my implemented `CSS` I can't set full height for `div`s

[this link](https://codepen.io/MahdiPishguy/pen/BaYPdyv) is what I in the code

my code result:

[image]

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.border {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.border-red {
  border-color: red !important;
}

.border-blue {
  border-color: blue !important;
}

.border-green {
  border-color: green !important;
}

.border-2 {
  border: 2px solid #000;
}

.border-1 {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
}

.left,
.right {
  width: 20%;
}

.middle {
  width: 60%;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.background-blue {
  background-color: #b3dcff;
}

.background-green {
  background-color: #b3ffd1;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.height-50 {
  min-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="fa">

<head>
  <title>Mahdi Pishguy</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row py-3 px-3">
    <div class="column text-center left background-blue">left</div>
    <div class="column middle background-green text-center">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="">Header</div>
        <div style="height: 100%;">
          Content
        </div>
        <div class="">Footer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column height-50 text-center right background-blue">right</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Consider learning, and using, CSS Grid; for example: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/tsxfckLb/ (CSS-Tricks article: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to make this, you have to put classes on header, content, footer and left and right. Also put a `containerName` class on your parent `div` that contains all these. Now it's too much to explain but in short words, you need to set height of all elements however you want it and spread the content how you desire.

Here is the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/wirdklap/pen/BaYPdvB).

Answer (score 1):

Add this in CSS to the desired `div`s:

```css
height: 100vh;
```

Answer (score 1):

you're welcome =)
https://codepen.io/MahdiPishguy/pen/BaYPdyv

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

#left {
  height: 100vh;
}
#right {
  height: 100vh;
}

.Header{
  height: 10vh;
}
.Content {
  height: 80vh;
}
.Footer{
  height: 10vh;
}
.py-3 {
/*     padding-top: 9px; */
/*     padding-bottom: 9px; */
}

.px-3 {
    padding-right: 9px;
    padding-left: 9px;
}

.mx-3 {
    margin-right: 9px;
    margin-left: 9px;
}

.my-3 {
    margin-top: 9px;
    margin-bottom: 9px;
}

.border {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.border-red {
    border-color: red !important;
}

.border-blue {
    border-color: blue !important;
}

.border-green {
    border-color: green !important;
}

.radius-symmetric-top {
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
}

.radius-symmetric-bottom {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
}

.radius-symmetric-left {
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
}

.radius-symmetric-right {
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
}

.border-2 {
    border: 2px solid #000;
}

.border-1 {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.column {
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
}

.left, .right {
    width: 20%;
}

.middle {
    width: 60%;
}

.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.background-blue {
    background-color: #b3dcff;
}

.background-green {
    background-color: #b3ffd1;
}

.text-center {
    text-align: center;
}

.height-50 {
    min-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype  html>
<html lang="fa">
<head>
    <title>Mahdi Pishguy</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="row py-3 px-3">
    <div id="left" class="column text-center left background-blue">left</div>
    <div class="column middle background-green text-center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="Header">Header</div>
            <div class="Content">
                Content
            </div>
            <div class="Footer">Footer</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="right" class="column height-50 text-center right background-blue">right</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```